# Function to define sequence $1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Given the following sequence:

$1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,\dots$

Let $x_1$ be the first element in the sequence, $x_2$ be the second, $x_3$ be the third and so on.

Let the function $f(i)$ be defined such that $f(i) = x_i$.

If $i$ is odd, then $f(i) = 1$.

If $i = 2 + 4j$ where $j$ is an integer, then $f(i) = 2$.

If $i = 4 + 8j$ where $j$ is an integer, then $f(i) = 3$.

If $i = 8 + 16j$ where $j$ is an integer, then $f(i) = 4$.

If $i = 16 + 32j$ where $j$ is an integer, then $f(i) = 5$.

Etc.

How do I define $f(i)$ in a compact, easy to understand equation?

Comment: Does $f(i) = \mbox{position of first 1 (from the right) in the binary expansion of }i$ work? EDIT: I wrote decimal instead of binary first

Comment: @JaneDoé you mean the binary expansion.

Comment: There's something I don't understand. You say "if $i$ is even, then $f(i)=1$. Afterward, you claim that "if $i=2+4j$, [...] then $f(i)=2$". But then $i=2+4j=2(1+2j)$ is also even, and as long as I am concerned $1\not=2$...

Comment: [OEIS sequence A001511](https://oeis.org/A001511)

Comment: @Dr.Mathva "even" was a typo for "odd".

Comment: But then, the first element cannot be $x_0$...

Comment: $x_0$ is 1, $x_1$ is 2, $x_2$ is 1, $x_3$ is 3 etc.

Comment: According to the text in your question, $x_1 = 1, x_2 =2, ...$. With this interpretation, we have $x_n = \nu_2(n)+1 = \max\{ v \in \mathbb{N} : 2^v | n \} + 1$ where $\nu_2(n)$ is the [p-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $n$ for $p = 2$.

Comment: Related (sort of):  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi.

Comment: I do not know if it counts as compact and easy: $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^k}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{x-1}{2^k}\right\rfloor$. Actually, the sum does not have to go to infinity, but only to $\log_2 x.$

Comment: How about $f(x) = 1+\log_2\left(\mathrm{gcd}\left(x,2^{\lfloor\log_2 x\rfloor}\right)\right)$

Answer (score 6):

I have seen the notation $\operatorname {ord_p}(n)$ for the exponent of a prime $p$ in the prime factorization of $n$.  Your sequence is then $x_n=\operatorname {ord_2}(n)+1$.  I don't know how common it is.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [A001511](https://oeis.org/A001511) sequence

> a(n) - 1 is the number of trailing zeros in the binary expansion of n.
>
> If you are counting in binary and the least significant bit is
> numbered 1, the next bit is 2, etc., a(n) is the bit that is
> incremented when increasing from n-1 to n. - Jud McCranie, Apr 26 2004

Answer (score 2):

Given the set of natural numbers written in binary $f(i\geq1)$ indicates the position of the last bit modified between the number $x_{i-1}$ and $x_i$. Here are the first 8:

$x_1= 0001_2;$
$x_2= 0010_2;$
$x_3= 0011_2;$
$x_4= 0100_2;$
$x_5= 0101_2;$
$x_6= 0110_2;$
$x_7= 0111_2;$
$x_8= 1000_2;$

The formula to derive this position is $f(i)= log_2 [(i-1)\oplus i+1]$.

Where $\oplus$ is the bitwise xor: $5\oplus6 = 101_2 \oplus 110_2 = 011_2 = 3$.

Taking full advantage of the Two's Complement implementation of modern processors, the esasiest formula is $f(i)= log_2 (i\&-i)$.

Where $\&$ is the bitwise and.